# Is it possible to show and hide elements of the same list depending on some values?

Tags: xamarin.forms, collectionview, visible

I have created a query that returns a list and I would like to hide or show an icon depending on a string values like this, but i dont know if its possible.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eiP57.png

I tried to binding the StackLayout but it didn't work.

**XAML**
The elements its on a CollectionView:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PB7cT.png

**VIEWMODEL**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/A5qjY.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/kuuiE.png

**VIEW**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/38ah4.png

the two icons should disappear in one of the elements

Any other solution?

Thank you so much in advance

Comment: Please do NOT post code as images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the `YouPage.xaml` code you posted, I found that the property `IsVisibleIcons` should belong to each item of the List you want to show, right?

Then, if you want to hide or show an icon based on the value of `IsVisibleIcons` of the `Item`, you need to change the value of the Item in the list (yours is `conversations`).But from the screenshot you shared , the `IsVisibleIcons` field appears to be a global variable, not a property of the `Item`.

```
foreach(var item in conversations){
  if(item.UserCreate == UserEmail){
        IsVisibleIcons = true;
        // please check above code, if it should be `item.IsVisibleIcons = true;`
    }   
}
```

Besides, I couldn't see the other code, but you also need to implement interface `INotifyPropertyChanged`  for your `Item` model.

Based on your code, I achieved a simple demo , you can refer to the following code:

**TestPage.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class TestPage : ContentPage 
{
    MyViewModel viewModel;
    public TestPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        viewModel = new MyViewModel();
    }

    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();

        myCollectioNView.ItemsSource = null;
        myCollectioNView.ItemsSource = viewModel.Items;

   // here I changed the value of property `IsVisibleIcons` of item
        foreach (Item item in viewModel.Items) {
            if (item.Name.Equals("test3")) {
                item.IsVisibleIcons = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**TestPage.xaml.cs**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="ListViewApp.TestPage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <CollectionView 
                 x:Name="myCollectioNView"
                 SelectionMode="Single"
                       >
                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid Padding="10">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                   <!--here, bind property `IsVisibleIcons`  -->

                            <Image Grid.RowSpan="2" 
                               Source="icon.png" 
                               Aspect="AspectFill"
                               HeightRequest="60" 
                               WidthRequest="60" 
                               IsVisible="{Binding IsVisibleIcons}"   
                                   />
                            <Label Grid.Column="1" 
                               Text="{Binding Name}" 
                               FontAttributes="Bold" />
                            <Label Grid.Row="1"
                               Grid.Column="1" 
                               Text="{Binding Description}"
                               FontAttributes="Italic" 
                               VerticalOptions="End" />
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            </CollectionView>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

**MyViewModel.cs**

```
public class MyViewModel 
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Item> Items { get; set; }

        public MyViewModel() {
            Items = new ObservableCollection<Item>();

            Items.Add(new Item { Name = "test1", Description= "Description 1", IsVisibleIcons = true });
            Items.Add(new Item { Name = "test2", Description = "Description 2", IsVisibleIcons = true });
            Items.Add(new Item { Name = "test3", Description = "Description 3", IsVisibleIcons = true });
            Items.Add(new Item { Name = "test4", Description = "Description 4", IsVisibleIcons = true });
            Items.Add(new Item { Name = "test5", Description = "Description 5", IsVisibleIcons = true });
            Items.Add(new Item { Name = "test6", Description = "Description 6", IsVisibleIcons = true });
    }
}
```

**Item.cs**

```
public class Item: INotifyPropertyChanged 
{
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public string Description { get; set; }
    // public bool IsVisibleIcons { get; set; }

    bool isVisibleIcons;
    public bool IsVisibleIcons
    {
        get => isVisibleIcons;
        set => SetProperty(ref isVisibleIcons, value);
    }

    bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (Object.Equals(storage, value))
            return false;

        storage = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```